# keep dropdown selected after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried keep retain selected item after reload triggered by on change value,

but I get this error on console "TypeError: o.nodeName is undefined[Learn More]"

my select :

```
<select onchange="showMov(this.value);" id="mov_type" name="mov_type" class="form-control" type="text"  />
   <option value="Selected">Choose Type</option>
   <option value="rusak">Rusak</option>
   <option value="dipinjam">Dipinjam</option>
   <option value="ditarik">Ditarik</option>
</select>
```

my js

```
function showMov(val){

var selectedItem = sessionStorage.getItem("SelectedItem");  
alert(selectedItem);

    if(selectedItem){
          var dropVal = $(this).val();
           sessionStorage.setItem("SelectedItem", dropVal);
    }

    if (val=="dipinjam"){
        $('#tarik_form').hide();
        $('#rusak_form').hide();
        $('#pinjam_form').show();
        $('#moveform').attr('action','asetpindah.php');
    }else if (val=="ditarik"){
        $('#pinjam_form').hide();
        $('#rusak_form').hide();
        $('#tarik_form').show();
        $('#moveform').attr('action','asettarik.php');
    }else if(val=="rusak"){
        $('#pinjam_form').hide();
        $('#tarik_form').hide();
        $('#rusak_form').show();
        $('#moveform').attr('action','asetrusak.php');
    }else{
        $('#pinjam_form').hide();
        $('#tarik_form').hide();
        $('#rusak_form').hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `selectedItem` would always be null since you're setting the selected value to the sessionStorage in the `if` block. Remove the if block and just set the selected option to the sessionStorage immediately:

```
function showMov(val) {
  sessionStorage.setItem('SelectedItem', val);

  switch (val) {
    case 'dipinjam':
      {
        $('#tarik_form').hide();
        $('#rusak_form').hide();
        $('#pinjam_form').show();
        $('#moveform').attr('action', 'asetpindah.php');
        break;
      }
    case 'ditarik':
      {
        $('#pinjam_form').hide();
        $('#rusak_form').hide();
        $('#tarik_form').show();
        $('#moveform').attr('action', 'asettarik.php');
        break;
      }
    case 'rusak':
      {
        $('#pinjam_form').hide();
        $('#tarik_form').hide();
        $('#rusak_form').show();
        $('#moveform').attr('action', 'asetrusak.php');
        break;
      }
    default:
      {
        $('#pinjam_form').hide();
        $('#tarik_form').hide();
        $('#rusak_form').hide();
      }
  }
}
```

Also, when the DOM is ready, that is when you should check if the sessionStorage has a `SelectedItem`:

```
$(function() {
  var selMovType = document.getElementById('mov_type');
  var selectedItem = sessionStorage.getItem('SelectedItem');

  if (selectedItem) {
    selMovType.value = selectedItem;
  }
});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r1vukpv4/).

Comment: oh now I get it why I check on the console always get null, I thought selected item need to be triggered first before declared, and I really thx for you giving me switch instead if, I definitely forgot using switch..

Answer (score 3):

You can use `localStorage` to store selected value:

```
 $('#mov_type').on('change', function() {
    // Save value in localstorage
    localStorage.setItem("mov_type", $(this).val());
 });
```

On page refresh, get the value from localStorage and set to the select:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#mov_type').length) {
        $('#mov_type').val(localStorage.getItem("mov_type"));
     }
});
```

`localStorage` is not supported in all browsers. You can use `shims` for that or fallback to `cookie`.

If you want to clear `localstorage` use

```
localStorage.removeItem("mov_type");
```

**UPDATE**

In your case you need to clear `localstorage` only if the page is `redirected` from another page. so you need to check if page gets `reloaded or refreshed`.

```
if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
    console.info( "This page is reloaded" );
} else {
    localStorage.removeItem("mov_type"); // clear localstorage
    console.info( "This page is not reloaded");
}
```

Not all browsers support `window.performance` correctly, so you may need to check

```
if (window.performance) {
  console.info("window.performance work's fine on this browser");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through and compare the value to set select attribute:

```
$('select#id option').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == dropVal) {
         $(this).attr('selected', true);
    }
});
```

Or

```
$("select#id option[value="+dropVal+"]").attr('selected', true);
```